# my float variable commission not displaying with arrays properly?

Tags: python

I am currently working on improving my commission program by implementing arrays into my program. However, I cannot properly display my commission results anymore. If I revert some array changes, I can display my commission fine. Can someone show me where I did wrong? I would appreciate any feedback on my code to the problem posted below. I'm a beginner and have only included code that I have learned up to this point

```
MAX = 10

def main():
    comp_name = [""] * MAX
    sales_amount = [0.0] * MAX
    total_sales_amount = 0.0
    commission = 0.0
    bonus = 0.0
    more_sales = 'Y'
    select_item = 0

    welcome_message()
    while more_sales == 'Y':
        comp_name[select_item] = get_comp_name()
        sales_amount[select_item] = get_sales_amount()
        total_sales_amount = total_sales_amount + (sales_amount[select_item] + sales_amount[select_item])
        more_sales = more_sales_input()
        select_item = select_item + 1
        commission += get_commission_calc(sales_amount)

    print_receipt(comp_name, sales_amount, select_item)

    bonus = get_bonus(commission)
    commission = commission + bonus

    print_totals(bonus, commission)

def welcome_message():
    print("Welcome to your commission calculator (v3)!")

def print_receipt(comp_name, sales_amount, select_item):
    sub_total = 0
    count = 0
    print("\nCompany Name                Unit Price  Total Price")
    print("------------                ----------  -----------")
    while count < num_items:
        print("{0:<15}".format(comp_name[count]), "\t\t$ ", format(sales_amount[count], ".2f"), "\t$ ", format(sales_amount[count], ".2f"))
        sub_total = sub_total + (sales_amount[count])
        count = count + 1
    print("-----------------------------------------------")
    print("Subtotal:                           $", format(sub_total, ".2f"))

def get_comp_name():
    comp = ""
    comp = input("\nEnter Company name: ")
    return comp

def more_sales_input():
    more = ""
    more = input("Do you have more sales to add? (y/n): ")
    more = more.upper()
    while more != "Y" and more!= "N":
        print("Invalid entry, either y or n.")
        more = input("Do you have more sales to add? (y/n): ")
        more = more.upper()
    return more

def get_sales_amount():
    sales = 0.0
    while True:
        try:
            sales = float(input("Please enter sales $ "))
            if sales < 0:
                print("Invalid, must be a positive numeric!")
            else:
                return sales
        except:
            print("Invalid, must be a positive numeric!")

def get_commission_calc(sales):
    commission = 0.0
    if sales >= 20000:
        commission = sales * .10
    elif sales >= 10000:
        commission = sales * .07
    else:
        commission = sales * .05
    return commission

def get_bonus(commission):
    if commission >= 1000:
        return + 500
    else:
        return 0

def print_totals(bonus, total_commission):
    if bonus > 0:
        print("\nYou earned a $500 bonus added to your pay!")
    else:
        print("\nYou did not yet meet requirements for a bonus!")
    print("\nYour commission is", '${:,.2f}'.format(total_commission))

main()
```

Comment: Can you include where does the exception happen?

Comment: @aaossa in function main commission += get_commission_calc(sales_amount), and in function get_commission_calc if sales >= 20000:

Comment: @aaossa sorry if my formatting is bad, still learning..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing 'sales_amount', which is a list, to 'get_commission_calc', which then compares the list with a number; hence the error.
What I believe you're trying to do is not passing the list, but the 'selected_item' of the list.
If that's the case, the function call should look more like this:

```
get_commission_calc(sales_amount[selected_item])
```

Comment: I need some extra help if you dont mind, I can't display my commission properly with your solution, if I revert the array changes, the commission results fine. Any tips?